# Making a slider picker in Android

Tags: android, menu, slider, picker

I'm trying to make a sliding picker that has circles above it showing you which one you currently have selected. I know I have seen this before, but don't know if this is something android can do by default, or if it has to be built from scratch. If it needs to be built from scratch, dose anyone know where to begin to make something like that.

here is a picture of what i'm trying to make:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using JQuery?

Comment: @Chad No, the teams are hard coded into the app in a defined array. I'm just trying to setup a way for people to be able to pick teams by swiping left or right between them, and having the white dot move to show where in the "list" they are.

Comment: Use a `ViewPager` to enable page swiping and then attach a [`ViewPagerIndicator`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) to visually display the current page. In particular, check out the `CirclePageIndicator`, which should do exactly what you're after.

Comment: @MH Thank you, the ViewPagerIndicator was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look into Pages concept in android that may helps you.
i.e Viewpager  fragemnt pager adapter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

or

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

Comment: Using this plus a ViewPagerIndicator as @MH sugested was what I needed, thanks!